# Use asp classic website as root website of mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp-classic

I have inherited an existing asp classic website, I want to create a MVC project and to include the asp classic site inside of it. i want to use the asp classic as the root website for that project and to use MVC mainly as an API that my asp classic will contact for requests.

I was thinking about making URL rewrite in MVC to move all requests to the asp classic pages, but I'm afraid it will break all forms requests

What would be the best practice to do that?

Comment: Add your effort in your question as [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33062604/edit)

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the first thing you need to do is make sure classic asp is enabled in IIS, it's disabled by default in current versions.

Classic asp pages should work perfectly well in your setup, start by creating a new MVC project then put your existing classic site in the root directory.  Your Classic pages will need their own database connection and they won't be able to share session variables with the .net stuff.  I find it easiest to regard setups like this as two sites sharing the same root folder.

I don't think it would be a good idea to use MVC for custom routing, use the [IIS url rewrite module](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) instead.

Comment: I have tried to use IIS url rewrite, the thing is that i can't distinct the asp classic routes from those of MVC, how would you distinct it? i prefer not to just "junk" my root folder with all the classic asp files and folders

Comment: So have your landing page in the root folder then spur off your MVC in one folder and your Classic ASP in another. You'll need to put your global.asa in the root. Use posting to side step session variable issues.